# ignore blank cells in range

Tags: vba, excel, range

I just have 2 ranges let's say Range("A1:A10") and Range("B1:B10") and then run this code:

```
Dim a, b, i, j
i = 2: j = 2


For Each a In range("A1:A10")
    For Each b In range("B1:B10")
        range("D" & i).Value = a
        range("E" & j).Value = b
        j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    Next b
Next a
```

End Sub

I need to create an `If` condition to skip blanks but it does not seem to be working.

**Second Question:**

If I were to name the range after setting them as a selection and xltodown how would you do that?

Comment: *`but it does not seem to be working`* because it's not there...*`how would you do that?`* what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried with this in the code
If a.Value <> "" Then
End If
If b.Value <> "" Then
End If

Comment: Ok now it is working. I must have done something wrong it was driving me crazy yesterday night. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
Dim a, b, i, j
i = 2: j = 2


For Each a In range("A1:A10")
    For Each b In range("B1:B10")
        If b.Value="" Then
          GoTo ContinueInnerForLoop
        End If
          range("D" & i).Value = a
          range("E" & j).Value = b
          j = j + 1
          i = i + 1
    ContinueInnerForLoop:
    Next b
Next a
```

since <kbd>**Continue**</kbd> is not supported in VBA, preferred way to use a label and jump to.

Hope it helps!